# How do I merge 2 adjacent columns in a CSV file into a single column, separated by comma? (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, csv, merge

I have a CSV file with 2 columns, latitude & longitude. I am trying to merge the 2 columns into 1, separated by a comma (no spaces).

Input CSV file, first 5 rows

```
latitude    longitude
35.1868     -106.6652
42.3688     -83.4799
40.3926     -79.9052
40.5124     -88.9883
38.5352     -90.0006
```

My goal is to take this CSV and create a new one with a single column with both values separated by a comma (no spaces in-between) using PowerShell. See the desired output below...

```
location
35.1868,-106.6652
42.3688,-83.4799
40.3926,-79.9052
40.5124,-88.9883
38.5352,-90.0006
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: import the CSV, iterate thru the resulting collection, build a new PSCustomObject and `-join` the two props from the source into one new property. then export it to a new CSV file. that seems to cover the ideas ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for the reply. I understand the concept is extremely simple for someone more experienced. It is the syntax I'm struggling with. Would you be willing write an example command based on the info I've provided?

Comment: sure! i'll post a snippet in a moment or two ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IMO easiest way is a Select-Object with a calculated property

```
Import-Csv .\input.csv | 
  Select-Object @{Name='Location';Expression={$_.latitude,$_.longitude -join ','}} |
    Export-Csv .\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

```
> Get-Content .\output.csv
"Location"
"35.1868,-106.6652"
"42.3688,-83.4799"
"40.3926,-79.9052"
"40.5124,-88.9883"
"38.5352,-90.0006"
```

## Edit

In case there are other columns which should not be affected by the merge,
see this modified `Select-Object`

```
Select-Object *,@{N='Location';E={$_.latitude,$_.longitude -join ','}} -Exclude latitude,longitude|
```

But the new column will then be the last one.

Answer (score 1):

the 1st ten lines are just a way to embed sample data in a script without needing to write it to a file & then read it back in. [*grin*]

use `Import-CSV` to get the real data into the script.

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
latitude, longitude
35.1868, -106.6652
42.3688, -83.4799
40.3926, -79.9052
40.5124, -88.9883
38.5352, -90.0006
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$LocationList = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Location = @($IS_Item.Latitude, $IS_Item.Longitude) -join ','
        }
    }

# on screen
$LocationList

# CSV file
$LocationList |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\JohnnyCarino_LocationList.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

screen output ...

```
Location         
--------         
35.1868,-106.6652
42.3688,-83.4799 
40.3926,-79.9052 
40.5124,-88.9883 
38.5352,-90.0006
```

CSV file content ...

```
"Location"
"35.1868,-106.6652"
"42.3688,-83.4799"
"40.3926,-79.9052"
"40.5124,-88.9883"
"38.5352,-90.0006"
```

Comment: @JohnnyCarino - you are most welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]